# Basic Scala OOP question - pass by reference?

Tags: oop, scala

I'm a little stumped at how silly this problem is and have a serious mindblank, but I thought I might ask anyway.

I have an object Foo, with several fields. I want a method that can change any of its fields depending on which one is passed in as a parameter. Like so:

```
class Foo {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
}

class Bar {
    def changeFooField(field : Int) = {
        field = 1        
    }
}
```

Can I not use it like so?:

```
changeFooField(foo.x)
```

If not, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No you cannot. You'll need to enclose the field value into an object:

```
class Field[T]( var value: T )

class Foo {
  val x = new Field(0)
  val y = new Field(0)
}

class Bar {
  def changeFooField( field: Field[Int] ) {
    field.value = 1
  } 
}

val f = new Foo
(new Bar).changeFooField( f.x )
println( f.x.value + " / " + f.y.value ) // prints "1 / 0"
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Yeah thought it wasn't possible without creating a new object wrapping the field.

Comment: @Dominic The basic problem, which hasn't explicitly been mentioned, is that `Int`s are immutable. If your field types are mutable, as in the example above, it's easy

Answer (score 16):

A common idiom is to pass an explicit setter method which takes care of changing the value.

```
class Foo {
  var x = 0
  var y = 0
}

class Bar {
  def changeFooField(setter: (Int) => Unit) = {
    setter(1)
  }
}

val foo = new Foo
val bar = new Bar
bar.changeFooField(foo.x = _) // or equivalent: bar.changeFooField((i: Int) => foo.x = i)

assert(foo.x == 1)
```

`(foo.x = _)` is a simple ad-hoc closure which allows write access to `foo.x`. There is no need in adding this setter API to `Foo` itself.

So, as it turns out, the setter method (`foo.x=` – or rather `foo.x_=`) is passed as an argument exactly as any other method is passed. You’ll have to remember that `val` and `var` in Scala don’t actually specify variables but create the methods which are then used to access the real (hidden) variables. (`val` only creates a getter method, whereas `var` of course creates both getter and setter).

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to all the answers above, this in fact is quite doable in Scala without writing any special wrapper classes.

First you need to know that for any non-private class var, such as the ones used in the original question, Scala automatically generates getters and setters.  So if we have a var called "color", Scala automatically creates a getter eponymously called "color" and a setter called "color_=".

Next you need to know that Scala lets you obtain a reference to any method by calling the special "_" method on it (which requires a space before it for disambiguation).

Finally putting these facts together, you can easily get a type-safe reference to any var's getter/setter and use that reference to dynamically set/get that var's value:

```
class Foo {
    var x = 0
}

object Foo {
    def setField[T](setter: T => Unit, value: T) {setter(value)}
    def getField[T](getter: () => T ) = {getter()}
}

val f = new Foo
val xsetter = f.x_= _
val xgetter = f.x _

Foo.setField(xsetter, 3)
println(f.x) //prints 3
println(Foo.getField(xgetter)) //prints 3
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want doesn't exist in Scala/Java. The closest thing would be passing around a setter function.

```
scala> class Foo {
     | var x = 0
     | var y = 0
     | val xSetter = (i:Int) => x = i
     | val ySetter = (i:Int) => y = i
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> def setField(setter:Int=>Unit) = setter(1)
setField: (setter: (Int) => Unit)Unit

scala> val f = new Foo
f: Foo = Foo@eb203b

scala> f.x
res0: Int = 0

scala> setField(f.xSetter)

scala> f.x
res3: Int = 1
```

Comment: +1 instead of defining a `setField`, I can just apply `xSetter`, like `f.xSetter(1)`. right? to have the same effect?

Comment: @Nishant but in that case you could also do `f.x = 1`…

Comment: @Debilski oh, right. :) so I am not sure why it's done so indirectly? I mean is there a pattern like this, in Scala?

Comment: ah, nevermind. Pass by reference is what is OP wanted to be explained.

Comment: It is done indirectly, because you cannot pass a `var` field itself in Scala. So, if you want to make the change inside some other method, you’ll either have to pass the class itself or a specific setter for the `var`.